# How do you pattern match for nil or a blank string in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

Here is a code sample with tests where I have a function that checks if the value passed in is in an allowable set of values and if it isn't, it raises an exception, but if the value passed in is nil or a blank string, it just returns false. The idea here is that any sort of blank value means is there is no value. If there is a non-blank value that doesn't match one of the valid values, then we do want to raise an exception because that value is invalid. Also imagine this value is coming from a command line argument or Phoenix request param where we can't control the input value be just nil, we have to check for all permutations of an empty value, nil, an empty string or a string containing just spaces.

```
ExUnit.start()

defmodule ValidColor do
  @valid_colors MapSet.new(~w[red green blue])

  def valid?(color) do
    cond do
      blank?(color) -> false
      MapSet.member?(@valid_colors, color) -> true
      true -> raise "invalid color"
    end
  end

  defp blank?(value) do
    case value do
      nil -> true
      v when is_binary(v) -> v =~ ~r/\A\s*\z/
      _ -> false
    end
  end
end

defmodule ValidColorTest do
  use ExUnit.Case, async: true

  test "nil" do
    refute ValidColor.valid?(nil)
  end

  test "empty string" do
    refute ValidColor.valid?("")
  end

  test "string with only blank characters" do
    refute ValidColor.valid?("     ")
  end

  test "invalid color" do
    assert_raise RuntimeError, "invalid color", fn ->
      ValidColor.valid?("yellow")
    end
  end

  test "valid color" do
    assert ValidColor.valid?("red")
  end
end
```

This seems to be a case when a `blank?` helper function is useful, as I have done in this example. There seems to be [a sentiment among Elixir programmers that this type of helper method is unnecessary and can be done with pattern matching](https://www.reddit.com/r/elixir/comments/5d1cgb/coming_from_ruby_whats_the_equivalent_of_blank/).

How can you implement a function like this with just pattern matching and not the `blank?` helper function?

Answer (score 15):

While all the answers given here are somehow correct, they are not *semantically* perfect. What you want is actually to treat `nil` as an empty string and reject it. Do it straightforward:

```
defp blank?(str_or_nil),
  do: "" == str_or_nil |> to_string() |> String.trim()
```

Please note, that this solution, unlike other given here so far, works with *all* the spaces, defined as spaces in UTF-8 specification.

Answer (score 4):

The `nil` case is easy:

```
defp blank?(nil), do: true
```

To check if a string consists of only whitespace characters, more involved pattern matching is required:

```
# Empty string is always blank.
defp blank?(""), do: true

# If the string's first byte is a space, tab, newline, or carriage return,
# we recursively check the remaining part of the string.
defp blank?(<<h, t::binary>>) when h in ' \t\n\r', do: blank?(t)

# Otherwise, it's not blank.
defp blank?(_), do: false
```

Comment: This, unfortunately, does not work with NBSP and 12 other spaces defined in UTF-8. [`String.trim/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/String.html#trim/1) does.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use a [`case/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#case/2):

```
def blank?(str) do
  case str do
    nil -> true
    "" -> true
    " " <> r -> blank?(r)
    _ -> false 
  end
end
```

NB: in this case we only consider spaces, pattern matching on "\n","\r" and "\t" must also be considered as @dogbert did in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Elixir functions can have multiple function heads. With this, it is pretty trivial to create a `blank?/1` helper function.

```
defp blank?(nil), do: false
defp blank?(""), do: false
defp blank?(_), do: true
```

Comment: This won’t pass _“string with only blank characters”_ test provided by OP.

Comment: You are correct. I didn't go through all of the tests, I just saw "but if the value passed in is nil or a blank string" and took blank string to mean empty.